# If Checkbox is checked, remove attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

```
<div class="span1">
     <input type="checkbox" value="l4" id="l4" field="" defaultValue="" appEditor="true"/>
</div>

<div class="span7">
     <input type="text" class="m-wrap span10" id="fld_l4" defaultValue="" editType="intEdit" appEditor="true" disabled />
</div>
```

What I want to do is, If checkbox is checked, remove disabled in the fld_l4.

How to do this with using Prototype.js or jQuery?

EDIT: I'm using prototype with jQuery
i'm getting an error: `Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.` By the way i replaced $ with jQuery for conflicts

EDIT2 : Solved.

```
this.l4     = editor.instance;
editor.observe(iconstants.KEY_CHANGE,this.levelCheckboxChanged.bindAsEventListener(this))
```

Inside levelCheckboxChanged:

```
levelCheckboxChanged: function(e) {

    if($("l4").checked == false) {
        $("fld_l4").disabled = true;
    } else {
        $("fld_l4").disabled = false;
    }
},
```

Comment: Check this out if you want to toggle disabled http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/suB2N/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way to do this with PrototypeJS

inside of your DOM loaded event

```
document.observe('dom:loaded',function(){

    $('l4').observe('click',function(){
        $('fld_l4').writeAttribute('disabled',this.checked);
    });

});
```

<strike>Plus you might want to change the id of '14' browsers do not like you starting id's with numbers - they let you do it but it is not part of the HTML spec</strike>

Comment: Thanks for the tip, and by the way it's not 14(fourteen), it's l4.     1 and l is very similar in this font :)

Comment: In final version, I added an observe for the checkbox and in key click event i use levelCheckboxChanged.bindAsEventListener(this);   Inside levelCheckboxChanged function I, do some magic like your example.(see edit) Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This way should work:

```
$("#l4").on("change", function () {
    $("#fld_l4").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J5Nt2/1/

Comment: It would work quite just the same way. A really small change needed. Updated the answer.

Comment: Is that code complete? If so, wouldn't it look like this: `checkCheckboxes = function() {`?

Comment: `!this.checked` there's neither need to use, nor benefit from using, jQuery to assess if something is checked or not.

Comment: I used jQuery to answer just because the OP mentioned that's what it was being used already. The question has been edited since then.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
$('#l4').change(function(){
if(this.checked){
$("#fld_l4").removeAttr('disabled');
 }    
})
```

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/gSqVD/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if( $("#l4:checked").length ) {
    $("#fld_l4").removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if( $("#l4").is(":checked") ) {  
   $('#fld_l4').removeAttr('disabled');
}
```